# How to get member Groups belongs to perticular customer or domain.?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I want to get all groups of user belongs to particular customer or domain ,not other groups.
I am using below code , but it is showing all groups. Some of groups does not belongs to that customer. I don't want to take that. I am using admin sdk and java.

```
  Directory.Groups.List groupsList = directoryService.groups().list();
        //groupsList.setCustomer(customerId);
        groupsList.setUserKey(memEmailID);
        groupsList.setMaxResults(15);

        groupsList.setPageToken(nextPageTokan);
        Groups groups = groupsList.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to limit the results to groups within the user's Google Apps instance. You would need to do this with two operations:

1. Get [all groups in the account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_domain_groups).
2. Get [all groups for the user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups).
3. Compare the results, only keeping the groups that are in both.

If you're performing these actions for multiple users in the account, obviously #1 only needs to be done once which will save some time.